# Replacing identicons with face-like avatars

Tags: script, fun

This is a tiny script replacing identicons on SE sites with face-like avatars provided by Gravatar.  Available as a  [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/replace-identicons-with-g/gfddlecdpjlfdolmencgaigijjgohldf), and as a source file below.

```
var i, t, images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
  t = images[i].src;
  if (t.indexOf('identicon')!=-1) {
    images[i].src = t.replace(/identicon/,'wavatar');
  }
}
```

(Should be matched to all SE sites of interest to the user.)

Sample screenshot (the list of new users on math.se):

[image: avatars]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as a userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Faces
// @version      1.0
// @description  http://stackapps.com/questions/6296/replacing-identicons-with-face-like-avatars
// @author       Normal Human
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match        *://stackapps.com/*
// @match        *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match        *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match        *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  var i, t, images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    t = images[i].src;
    if (t.indexOf('identicon') != -1) {
      images[i].src = t.replace(/identicon/, 'wavatar');
    }
  }
})();
```